# When trying to run Ec2 with RDS, connection times out. Do my security group rules look right?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I have set up an Ec2 with files from S3 and a MySQL RDS. If I run my Node app locally, I can connect to the RDS and it works just fine. But when I SSH into the Ec2 and `npm start`, it never connects and the connection times out. Only error is Error Connection Timed Out.

I have a screenshot below of the RDS's security group inbound rules. Notice I have a single IP for my desktop (which is how I was able to connect by running the app locally).

This is the first time I've set up an Ec2 and RDS. Does anything look off? I know I don't need all of those rules, but what am I missing? How can I troubleshoot? Also attached screen shot of EC2's outbound SG rules.

Also, I configured a MySQL server on the Ec2 and can SSH into the Ec2 and connect to the RDS database just fine from that. Is there another simple way I can test if the Ec2 is connecting to RDS?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the initial problem was not actually with the EC2 to RDS connection, although the suggestions above are essential. The home page of the app does not require any data from the database but it was not loading at all, so I finally figured out it was a connection problem between my computer and the EC2 using the public IP address. This should have been something to check earlier - the clues being the home page conundrum and the successful MySQL connection on SSH.

I simply needed to add an inbound rule on the EC2's security group for port 3000. It had been set to All Traffic. Any idea why All Traffic would not work?

Answer (score 1):

If that first TCP rule is referencing security group attached to your EC2 instance from which you are trying to reach this RDS instance then the traffic will automatically be allowed at this SG and all the other rules (except for connection from your notebook) are redundant.

Note that you need to allow outbound communication on SG attached to your EC2 instance as well to be able to reach RDS. Easiest way, and probably the best one is to reference SG of RDS in the same way you are doing it in RDS SG.

```
TCP 3306 -> destination: SG-<sg-attached-to-your-rds>
```

If the problem still persists then you should check your NACL configuration (if your instance is not in the same subnet with your RDS instance) and allow communication between those subnets for this specific type of traffic.

Comment: We performed the same lab at our end and tried connecting to RDS through EC2 instance running an npm service, the connection was successful without any error. So can you please confirm the port number of node on which your npm service running, also make sure that you have stopped MySQL service running on EC2 instance locally when you start npm service and try to connect RDS. Please provide logs of netstat for port 3306 which will help us in providing a better solution for your query.

Comment: @Matus-Dubrava I added outbound communication on the EC2 SG and will put a photo of it in the question. Still no connection. I believe the two are on the same private subnet.